# Adding tags through checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to add tags to posts through simple_form checkboxes and the acts_as_taggable_on gem. There are a few questions on it already but i have not been able to find a method that works. I want the following tag options: world, politics, tech and sports.

Right now i have this in my _form:

```
 <%= f.label :tag_list %>
<%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'world', nil %>
<%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'politics', nil %>
<%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'tech', nil %>
<%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'sports', nil %>
```

I have this in my posts model:

```
acts_as_taggable
```

and here is the controller:

```
 def index
  if params[:tag]
  @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
 else
 @posts = Post.all
 end
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

The problem is when i click on a checkbox it doesn't save that tag to the post. Everything works if i use the standard 'add your own tags, separate by commas'.

Answer (score 3):

I was working with strong parameters, so I did the following.

Assuming your model is "Post", add this method into your posts_controller.rb file

```
def create
  params[:post][:tag_list] = params[:post][:tag_list].join(',')
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :tag_list)
  end
```

And in posts/_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for post, remote: true do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.input :tag_list, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'
  = link_to "Cancel", "#", class: 'btn', data: {dismiss: 'modal'}
```

Comment: I liked this method. I ended up setting a 'before_action' for my :create, :edit actions to setup a variable for storing the collection array too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the param[:tag_list] is converted to an Array by Rails and thus not what is expected by acts_as_taggable_on.

I suspect that doing the following in the controller (Before updating/creating it) might solve the problem:

```
  params[:tag_list] = params[:tag_list].join(", ")
```

Comment: New to rails and not quite sure how this would look in the controller. I edited the question with what my controller is now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tested that form and it works for me. Wasn't sure if ActsAsTaggableOn would take an array instead of a string into tag_list but it seems to parse it fine.

Do your params look correct on submit? IE:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blargh", "blog_post"=>{"tag_list"=>["tech", "sports"]}, "commit"=>"Update BlogPost", "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Yep, the params look just like that. Hmm.

Comment: Can you post your whole controller and the relevant view? Any there's nothing suspicious in your server log around the commit?

Comment: Posted the view in the question. Here's the server log:Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>blahblah"=", "post"=>{"title"=>"test", "country"=>"", "description"=>"test", "tag_list"=>["sports"], "image_remote_url"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add Event"}. As for the controller that's the whole posts#index function. The view is in a partial thats called by the posts index page if that makes any difference.

Comment: What about your #update? Do you see the commit transaction to the db after that? No rollbacks? What happens when you call that object in rails console? That view ought to work, provided you have the tag route set up.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I recently ran into same issue and thought I'd post my solution. Using Rails 5.0.0 and acts-as-taggable-on I had exactly the same problem: when using f.text_field, all tags and taggings get saved nicely, but as soon as I changed to f.check_box with :multiple => true, nothing got saved.

The solution was in strong parameters. Because the parameters submitted by text_field look like this:

```
"blog_post"=>{"tag_list"=>"tech, sports"}
```

and params submitted by by the checkbox form look like this:

```
"blog_post"=>{"tag_list"=>["tech", "sports"]}
```

then we need to edit our strong params in the controller from

```
params.require(:blog_post).permit(:foo, :tag_list)
```

to

```
params.require(:blog_post).permit(:foo, :tag_list => [])
```

to permit the array that gets submitted.